# Performing calculation for multiple rows from one sheet on input data on a different worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a dataset on Worksheet "Results" and the dataset is in cells B8:K900 (Actual data in these cells, rest all cells have other meta information this dataset)

Each column of this data set refers to a certain variable like B column has Steam flow, C column has Steam temp etc.

I would like to use these values to plug into a calculator on another sheet, Row by row.

Eventually I will have results in 2 Cells on another sheet which I would like to bring back to Column L and M

Code so far, (I am getting error on first line "ws1.Range("B").Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("B6")"  while debugging) :

Note: Goal Seek and Rerun are 2 macros which I would like run after one row of Scenario is in input, as these will help to get results. Hence I have added them in loop also

Any help would be appreciated.

```
Sub Goal_Seek()
Range("I33").GoalSeek Goal:=Range("P33").Value, ChangingCell:=Range("E3")
End Sub


Sub Rerun()
Do Until Range("P20") = Range("P22").Value
    Range("P20") = Range("P22").Value
Loop
End Sub


Sub Calcs()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, ws3 As Worksheet, ws4 As Worksheet, ws5 As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws1 = wb.Worksheets("Results")
Set ws2 = wb.Worksheets("PI Data")
Set ws3 = wb.Worksheets("Mole_avg")
Set ws4 = wb.Worksheets("eff")
Set ws5 = wb.Worksheets("FlueGas")
Set rng = ws1.Range("B8:M9")
    For Each Row In rng.Rows
        ws1.Range("B").Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("B6")
        ws1.Range("C").Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("B3")
        ws1.Range("D").Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("B4")
        ws1.Range("E").Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("B5")
        ws1.Range("G").Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("B7")
        ws1.Range("H").Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("B8")
        ws1.Range("I").Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("B9")
        ws1.Range("J").Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("B10")
        ws1.Range("K").Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("B11")

        Application.Run "Goal_Seek"
        Application.Run "Rerun"

        ws3.Range("P17").Copy Destination:=ws1.Range("L")
        ws3.Range("T22").Copy Destination:=ws1.Range("M")
    Next Row
End Sub
```

Comment: **Which** error do you get? Note that `Range("B")` is no valid address for a range. If you mean the whole column B you need to use `Columns("B")` or you need to add a row number `Range("B" & row)`. Note that it is not possible to copy the whole column B into cell B6 because that does not fit!

Comment: The error I am getting is Run time error '1004':
Method  'Range' of object'_Worksheet' failed

I have selected range because First input values to the calculator are from B8:K8 and then I will get results in L8 and M8.

Similarly next input values will be B9:K9 and then results should appear on L9 and M9

And so forth.....

Comment: The error is because of the reason I explained in my first comment. Fix your addresses. You probably need to use `Range("B" & row.row)`

Comment: Thanks for comment, 

Writing code as ws1.Range("B" & rng.Row).Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("B6")

Now it is working. However not getting result.

1. When the results are being copied from WS3 sheet to WS1, it is actually copying formula instead of actual value
2. Secondly The loop appears to drop out after first row

Any additional assistance will be appreciated

Comment: Because you did not do what I suggested but something different (which then obviously does not work). I said use `row.row` and you used `rng.Row` that is not the same! • If you only want to copy the values then you do that like `ws2.Range("B6").Value = ws1.Range("B6").Value` note that the destination has to be left of the `=` sign here!

Comment: It worked. thanks!